# svn working dir path

Tags: svn

i create an svn repo with

`svnadmin create SVNrep`

after that i create a dir and import it to the rep

`mkdir test`

`touch test/test.txt`

`svn import test file:///Users/sara/SVNrep/test -m "Initial import"`

My question is, where svn stores the file that i commit in my filesystem?
I check the the SVNrep but there arent any files i commited.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files you commit to a Subversion repository are stored in the Subversion repository database. They are not stored as actual files on disk (so you won't find `test.txt` in your SVNRep directory).

Comment: Hi Greg, if i commit a 1 GB File to the repo an make a `du -h SVNrep` the size is less than 1MB.

Comment: The Subversion repository database stores compressed files. You probably committed a file that was easily compressed.

Comment: Thx. `dd if=/dev/random of=outputrandom.dat  bs=1024  count=102400` is easy to compress =). `du -h REPO` looks much better with `dd if=/dev/urandom of=a.log bs=10M count=1`